# How do I calculate percentages in a Venn diagram

Tags: combinatorics

A city has two newspapers, the sun and the advertiser. 56% of the people read the sun, 71% of the people read the advertiser and 18% read neither newspaper.

Comment: 18% read neither, so 82% read at least one. What happens when you add up those who read the Sun and Advertiser? Do you double-count someone, possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this image

[image]

then
$$
a+x=56,\\
b+x=71,\\
y=18,\\
a+b+x+y=100
$$